# ckeditor in rails with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ckeditor

I am using ck editor in rails having database mongo db. I followed the link https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor  . I am succes in doing work with the help of ckeditor.
since my view.html.erb code is like this

```
<%= f.cktext_area :description, :toolbar => 'Easy', :width => 800, :height => 200 %><br>
```

and my show page is

```
<%= raw@department.description %>
```

it does not works for file cases.
I have my model attachment_file.rb is

```
class Ckeditor::AttachmentFile < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_mongoid_attached_file :data,
                            :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"

  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 100.megabytes
  validates_attachment_presence :data

  def url_thumb
    @url_thumb ||= Ckeditor::Utils.filethumb(filename)
  end
end
```

It is working for image cases but not working for zip file or any attachement. when it comes to the file cases it can upload file successfully with its path. but to download that file by user it doesnot work. I mean backend works properly for all features. But lacks to download that uploaded file stops by

```
`javascript:void(0)/*130*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found the answer of this problem . First run this in terminal.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ckeditor-3.7.1
```

follow this path in your computer since i am using linux and my gem file locates here.

```
 /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ckeditor-3.7.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/attachment/dialogs
```

and open attachement.js file and edit it with the code that u find from tha above link.
[click](https://github.com/netoneko/ckeditor/blob/44ce6924398e86e5775a78a9b7aa52be3018c6b0/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/attachment/dialogs/attachment.js)

Now ck editor will works for file attachment also.

Comment: Correct way of doing it is changing:
`gem 'ckeditor'`
to
`gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git://github.com/netoneko/ckeditor.git'`
in your Gemfile

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you encounter [this](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/19) bug in CKeditor:

It sugests adding before filter as fix eg:

```
  # app/model/department.rb

  before_save :fix_ckeditor_attachment_paths

  def fix_ckeditor_attachment_paths
    if self.description.index(/_cke_saved_href/)
      self.description = self.body.gsub(/_cke_saved_href/, 'href')
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did u use ck editor in rails with mongodb database and it worked fine?

Comment: I just set up sample app and it's works. Here is a github [repo](https://github.com/dmitriybudnik/Rails-CKeditor-Mongoid-and-Paperclip)  for your reference. There was minor glitches seting it up, but I don't think you encounter same issues.

Comment: Thanks for this repo. I  tried it . In Your  ck editor I couldn't find the option to attach zip file. For image i already did. I want to upload zip file from back side and download it from frot side....          try edit this <%= f.cktext_area :notes, :toolbar => 'Easy', :width => 800, :height => 400 %> and click the icon between image upload and flash. That is (Insert attachment) I want to work this function in ck editor.

Comment: I'm new to CKeditor, finding file upload wasn't easy) I think I googled to youtube to actually find it. I used to attach a Pdf file clicking the 'link' and using one of tabs there. I suppose you may attach whenever file you want the same way.

Comment: If u have any idea about using Insert attachment function work properly tthen share me . It is right that giving link also works but in this case your link become rough. It displays all  path like /ckeditor_assets/attachments/503f4fc56d7ab8d360000002/165-edit-multiple.zip?1346326469. It could be better if we can make Download link and after clicking that download link, user can download . Do you have any idea about this?